# Error: NoSucmMethoDerror:close 'String' has no instance getter 'text'

Tags: android, flutter

I have come across this error:

> NoSucmMethoDerror:close 'String' has no instance getter 'text'. Receiver:"connexion" Tried calling:text

[image]

Comment: You appear to have misspelled the error you are getting. Please fix that in the post.